# Attach metadata to image using Photo Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photosframework

I have successfully saved an image to `Photo Library` using Photo Framework API's after user selected that image from library using `UIImagePickerController`.

As I am capturing image inside my app, I have to take care of the metadata. I could save location & creationDate to the newly captured image and saved it into library.

But the problem is that I want to attach a ton of other properties, I mean I want to attach `EXIF` & `TIFF` properties.

There are a lot of properties in `EXIF` like this,

`kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal`
`kCGImagePropertyExifMaxApertureValue`
`kCGImagePropertyExifSpatialFrequencyResponse`
`kCGImagePropertyExifLensModel`

How am I supposed to get these values from the current device and attach it to image and save it to `Photo Library`?

Here is the complete code which I am using to save an Image to `Photo Library` after taking it from `UIImagePickerController`. I would like to put attaching metadata lines somewhere in this function before saving it to `Photo Library`.

```
//MARK: Saving an Image to PhotoLibrary and taking back the PHAsset

    class func savingThis(image : UIImage, completion : (asset : PHAsset?) -> ())
    {
        var localIdentifier : String?
        let imageManager = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()

        imageManager.performChanges({ () -> Void in

            let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)

            request.location = LocationManager.sharedInstance.locationManager.location
            request.creationDate = NSDate()

            // Add more properties here - somewhere EXIF, TIFF....

            if let properAsset = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset {
                localIdentifier = properAsset.localIdentifier
            }
            else {
                completion(asset: nil)
            }

            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if let properLocalIdentifier = localIdentifier {

                    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([properLocalIdentifier], options: nil)

                    if result.count > 0   {
                        completion(asset: result[0] as? PHAsset)
                    }
                    else {
                        completion(asset: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completion(asset: nil)
                }
        })
    }
```

Is this a dumb question? I don't have to use Photos Framework if there is another way to attach metadata, whatever way, I just wanna attach it. I don't know. Let me know your suggestions?

Comment: Cannot say for sure if this would work, as I can't test at the moment. However, I have done this with other custom values:
    let date = NSDate();
    setxattr(path, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal, date, sizeof(date), 0, 0)

Comment: @macandyp Date or Time is easiest value to attach what about other properties, Something like this? ```kCGImagePropertyExifMaxApertureValue``` where I can find the value for this?.  Could you please give me more info on this ```NSData``` thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208277/metadata-exif-tiff-etc-in-photokit this is example how you cad do this

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Yes I could see that I can attach ```Author```, ```CopyRight```.. etc. These are string values which I can input to the dictionary. I am talking about values like this ```kCGImagePropertyExifMaxApertureValue```? Where will you find the value for this? or this ```kCGImagePropertyExifLensModel```.

Comment: All these values are Constants. And should be used as keys in youre dictionary

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Thats interesting... Looks like I can attach any value for this key. Ok got it.